# R-Studio push and pull without username and password with GIT and 2 factor auth doesn't work?

Tags: r, git, authentication, rstudio, rstudio-server

I am using R-Studio on Ubuntu 17.1.
How to make push and pull to/from GIT repository work without username and password if GIT is protected with 2 factor auth.

I have tried to put the public key to GIT but it still asks me for username password when I want to push/pull.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When syncing, make sure you are using the SSH URL (git@github.com: ...) provided by github, not the https url (https://github.com/ ....)